# Android tablet emulator 10 inch 320dpi does not load layout-sw720dp

Tags: android, dpi, android-screen-support

This is probably an easy question, but i am just overlooking something.
I have an Android emulator with the following specs:

[image: Android emulator specs 10 inch tablet]

In my app I provide different layouts:

```
 res\layout
 res\layout-sw600dp
 res\layout-sw720dp
```

But this emulator loads the regular layout.
I have another emulator with 160dpi and the rest of the specs are the same.
This one does load the sw720dp layouts.

Why doesn't the 10 inch 320dpi emulator loads the sw720dp layout?

Comment: did you specify the support screen tag in androidmenifest.xml?

Comment: no, because i want to support all screens.
I think that is also not necessary because the other tablet layout does work.

Comment: Note that a 320dpi 1280x800 device is not going to be a 10in tablet. Just some quick rough math: `(sqrt(1280^2 + 800^2))/320` gives you ~4.7in.

Comment: someone voted the question down, sorry for missing this obvious calculation. I am a newbie and this question proves it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

```
 px = dp * (dpi / 160)
 dp = px / (dpi /160)
```

With 1280x800 320dpi, sw = 800, than you get:

```
 dp = 800 / (320 / 160) = 400dp
```

That is why it does not load res/layout-sw720dp or 600dp.

Solution would be to make sw400dp resources.